# Django view, how to change deleting an object

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name of country", max_length=100, default="Australia")
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="number of country", default="1")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class World(models.Model):
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="New Map", max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, when i create world with few countries inside i have this view:

```
def my_world(request, pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'game/my_world.html', {'world': world})
```

and html file:

```
{% for country in world.country.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'game.views.delete_country' pk=country.pk %}">{{ country.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

delete view:

```
def delete_country(request, pk):
    country = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=pk)
    country.delete()
    return render(request, 'game/my_world.html', {'world': world})
```

url:

```
url(r'^world/(?P<pk>[%&+ \w]+)/$', views.my_world),
url(r'^world/(?P<pk>[%&+ \w]+)/$', views.delete_country, name='delete_country'),
```

That's all what i invented

Now i have in my_world list of countries and when i click one of this it is deleted. I want to change it:

1. how change it to delete country from choosen world but only within this world?
2. How after this automatically return to this my_world?(probably something with primary key but current option does not work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to delete the country altogether, but just remove it from the specific World, then you need some way of identifying which World you mean. You'll probably need to do that in the URL:

```
url(r'^world/(?P<world_pk>\d+)/(?P<country_pk>\d+)/$', views.delete_country, name='delete_country'),
```

and you can link to it in the template with:

```
{% url 'game.views.delete_country' world_pk=world.pk, country_pk=country.pk %}
```

Now the view can get the World and remove its specific country. Note that the answer to your second question is to use the `redirect` shortcut:

```
def delete_country(request, world_pk, country_pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
    country = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=pk)
    world.country.remove(country)
    return redirect("my_world", pk=world.pk)
```

Also note it's a pretty bad idea to have the delete action triggered by a simple link. Normally any action that modifies the database - especially one that deletes something - should be done via a form post.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! Now i understand how to make views like this, but i have one question about url: Now i get message "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^world/(?P<world_pk>\d+)/(?<country_pk>\d+)/$" is not a valid regular expression: syntax error". I see it is a problem probably with this url only, but how to reapair it?

Comment: Sorry, missing the `P` in the second expression.

Comment: Ok thank you, i also deleted "," between world.pk, country_pk in template because with this it didn't work. But after that i have no idea how change this error: when i click on country in my world i get a message "global name 'pk' is not defined" about this line: "world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)